# Copy List Item duplication

Tags: list, workflow, calendar

I have a bunch of clients setup for a site each with their own tracking gnatt chart. I have modified this so I can send a Copy List Item to to a calendar for that customer. Now When I run the workflow (manually as Automatic seems to not work at the moment) it copies all the items again so it will duplicate the older ones on the calendar.

I'm having trouble on stopping this can anyone help me?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to check if there's an existing item which matches yours by default. The copied item will just be a new appointment instance with it's own ID, by coincidence having the same text as an existing one as far as SharePoint is concerned.

If you want to implement this check, write a custom code workflow which first checks if there's an existing item and then either overwrites / updates it or skips copying all together. If you really want to do it the correct way, you should store the original appointment id in your copied version for reference. That way you won't be dependant upon a matching appointment text (since that can quite easily change too).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sadly I am not really good with code, can you offer any links to help me out?

Comment: In my opinion it's the only way to properly solve this issue. Search for "SharePoint 2010 workflow" on Youtube and you'll find some examples.